# Does assigning multiple return values by index impact performance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, return-value

Lately i wrote some Python 3 code along the lines of

```
def foo():
    return x, y

def bar():
    data = {"some": "values"}
    data["x"], data["y"] = foo()
    return data
```

which my (JetBrains) IDE prompted to correct to

```
def bar():
    return {"some": "values"
            "x": foo()[0],
            "y": foo()[1]}
```

To my intuition this would call foo() twice though and only use one return value in each case. Does Python interpret the foo() method in the second bar() correctly to be only executed once or does it differ from simultaneously assigning both return values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Ignore JetBrains IDE's suggestion. Calling `foo` twice is unnecessary. The feature you are using is known as sequence unpacking and requires `foo` to be run once.

Setting dictionary values, on the other hand, has O(1) complexity and is unlikely to be your bottleneck.

In my opinion, your solution is also clearer than JetBrains IDE's alternative.